# Automorphisms of curves of arithmetic genus one

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Take a projective curve of arithmetic genus one over a finite field $k=\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. The curve is allowed to have nodes but not cusps. How large can the automorphism group of the curve be? For elliptic curves it should be a semidirect product of the group of rational points and the group of automorphism preserving a fixed rational point but I have no mental picture for singular curves.

Comment: If you add rational tails you can make the automorphism as large as you want.

Comment: @Angelo assume the curve is geometrically irreducible.

Comment: If it's geometrically irreducible and has arithmetic genus 1, it is either smooth, or it is a geometrically rational curve with a single node. This last case is not very hard to analyze.